# Convert values ranging from (0 to +1) to negative values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-conversion

I have question regarding the conversion of values in the data frame in R. I have the calculated data that consists of values ranging from (0 to 0.999) and (1 to infinity). I would like to retain the (1 to infinity) values as it is in the table, however, would like to convert (0 to 0.999) to negative values for the purpose of plotting the heatmap using the formula `(-1/[(0 to 0.999)])` . Below is the example of my input and output data. Please assist me with this.

```
Input_Data <- read.csv(file = "./Synthetic_Data_Input.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = 1)
Output_Data <- read.csv(file = "./Synthetic_Data_Output.csv",stringsAsFactors = FALSE, row.names = 1)

dput(Input_Data)
structure(list(Sample_1 = c(0.942972, 1.00812, 1.10038, 1.19572, 
1.28194, 1.37384, 1.75378, 2.56584, 2.56584), Sample_3 = c(0.517607, 
0.935699, 0.567427, 0.572821, 0.795282, 0.541105, 1.03596, 2.78013, 
0.189337)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene_4", "Gene_7", 
"Gene_2", "Gene_3", "Gene_6", "Gene_9", "Gene_5", "Gene_8", "Gene_1"
))


dput(Output_Data)
structure(list(Sample_1 = c(-1.060476875, 1.00812, 1.10038, 1.19572, 
1.28194, 1.37384, 1.75378, 2.56584, 2.56584), Sample_3 = c(-1.93196769, 
-1.068719749, -1.762341235, -1.745746053, -1.257415609, -1.848070153, 
1.03596, 2.78013, -5.281587857)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Gene_4", 
"Gene_7", "Gene_2", "Gene_3", "Gene_6", "Gene_9", "Gene_5", "Gene_8", 
"Gene_1"))
```

Thank you,
Toufiq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can change only the values that are in range of `0 to 0.999`.

```
inds <- Input_Data <= 0.999
Input_Data[inds] <- -1/Input_Data[inds]

Input_Data
#        Sample_1  Sample_3
#Gene_4 -1.060477 -1.931968
#Gene_7  1.008120 -1.068720
#Gene_2  1.100380 -1.762341
#Gene_3  1.195720 -1.745746
#Gene_6  1.281940 -1.257416
#Gene_9  1.373840 -1.848070
#Gene_5  1.753780  1.035960
#Gene_8  2.565840  2.780130
#Gene_1  2.565840 -5.281588
```

Comment: Elegant solution.

Comment: Hi @Ronak Shah, I am getting an error as given below, is this because of the missing values in my data: Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, inds, value = c(-4484.10385184521,  : 
  'value' is the wrong length

Comment: @MohammedToufiq Change `inds` to `inds <- Input_Data <= 0.999 & !is.na(Input_Data)` to remove `NA` values.